# How make the angled (pointed) thumb for a slider control 

Tags: wpf, slider

In the standard wpf slider control you specify TicksPlacement and TicksFrequency and you get the tickbar along with the angled / pointed thumb which is pointing in the direction of the tick bar.

I have my own slider style (Control Template that is) and I'd like to make the thumb pointed like that. What's the easiest way to do that?

I took a look at the control template in Blend for the wpf slider and it was *NOT* obvious how that was done.

Anybody know of an easy way to toss that in to a control template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you already have the default Styles and ControlTemplates, if not you can download those from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358533%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Click the link for the associated theme, then click Download sample.

With the Aero theme, the pointed thumbs are defined using the Styles with the keys "VerticalSliderLeftThumbStyle" and "HorizontalSliderDownThumbStyle", so you can search for those terms.

The ControlTemplate in these styles uses several Path objects, whose data is defined earlier in the file. So you'd need to copy all referenced resources.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see it now. Thanks for pointing out the resource key name that provides that functionality, that's what I needed. Thanks!!!